# JS FS, чтение директории, сортировка и получение результата синхронно. async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, fs

Имеется следующий код:

```
function getFilesFromPathByModifiedTime(){
    let file;
    fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        file =  files.map((fileName) => {
            return {
                name: fileName,
                time: fs.statSync(path + '/' + fileName).mtime.getTime()
            };
        })
            .sort((a, b) => { return b.time - a.time; })
            .map((v) => { return v.name; });
    });
    console.log(file); // -> undefined
    //setTimeout(() => console.log(file), 1000) // -> Object;
}
```

Данная функция выполняет чтение директории и сортировку всех файлов в ней по дате изменения.

Собственно вопрос заключается в том, как правильно разместить в ней async/await чтобы поместить полученные значения в переменную.

Фунцкия асинхронная и закомментированный кусочек кода внизу через 1 секунду выводит все необходимые данные.

Comment: Довольно глупо делать асинхронное чтение директории и при этом синхронный statSync

Comment: асинхронное чтение директории и не нужно было мне, нашел код на просторах интернета и решил поправить под себя, попутно оставляя синхронные функции, но что-то пошло не так..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mapFiles = fileName => ({
  name: fileName,
  time: fs.statSync(path + '/' + fileName).mtime.getTime(),
});

async function getFilesFromPathByModifiedTime() {
    // Дожидаемся выполнения промиса, что бы получить значение.
    const files = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
        if (err) reject(err)
        resolve(files);
      })
    );

    // Тут нам уже доступные файлы
    const file = files.map(mapFiles)
        .sort((a, b) => b.time - a.time)
        .map((v) => v.name);

    console.log(file);
}
```

А еще есть вот такая библиотека https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-promisify

Comment: Я предпочитаю [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra), она хороша тем, что позволяет использовать себя вместо `fs` без изменения уже существующего кода.